# The transformation between two types of parse trees

Tags: python, parsing, tree

I have a training set contains two types of NLP parse trees ([PSG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrase_structure_grammar) and [CCG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_categorial_grammar)), which have a common source sentence. My goal is given a sentence with only one type of parse tree, using a set of rules learned from the training data, transforming the given type into another type of parse tree.

For example, given two types of parse trees i and ii, say:

```
i: (S (N John) (VP (V hit) (NP (D the) (N ball) ) ) )

ii: (S (NP John) (S\NP ((S\NP)/NP hit) (NP (NP/NP the) (NP ball) ) ) )
```

They both have the same leaf nodes but with different syntactic tags (POS tags and CCG tags, respectively).

My way is to create a mapping between the corresponding nodes of each tree:

```
pos_cat_map = defaultdict(int)  # A map from (POS tags, CCG tags) to their counts
cat_map = defaultdict(int)  # A map from CCG tags to its counts

# Generate a hierarchical tree structure,  
# @para: psg_sent is the sentence i, ccg_sent is ii. 
psg_tree = generate_psg_tree(psg_sent)  
ccg_tree = generate_ccg_tree(ccg_sent)

# Updating the container iteratively.
update_mapping(psg_tree, ccg_tree, pos_cat_map, cat_map)
```

The function `update_mapping` is defined as follows:

```
def update_mapping(psg_tree, ccg_tree, pos_cat_map, cat_map):
    ...
    if isinstance(psg_tree, PSGTree):
        # Update the root node
        pos_cat_map[(psg_tree.root, ccg_tree.cat)] += 1
        cat_map[ccg_tree.cat] += 1
        if ...
            update_mapping(psg_tree.left_child, ccg_tree.head, pos_cat_map, cat_map)
            update_mapping(psg_tree.right_child, ccg_tree.sister, pos_cat_map, cat_map)
        ...
    elif isinstance(psg_tree, PSGLeafNode):
        # Update the leaf node
        ...
        try:
            if psg_tree.word == ccg_tree.word:
                pos_cat_map[(psg_tree.syn, ccg_tree.cat)] += 1
                cat_map[ccg_tree.cat] += 1
            else:
                raise TransException("Two types of words are not matching: %s %s" % (tct_tree.word, ccg_tree.word))
        ...
    ...
```

After doing this, I got a map containing the mappings from PSG leaf nodes to CCG leaf nodes, some examples like:

```
==============
== p(pos|cat)
==============
v|S{sub}\NP 0.341598
vN|SP/SP 0.034783
a|[S/S]/[S/S] 0.014184
vN|NP 0.041867
p|[S/S]/[S{obj}\NP] 1.000000
...
```

Then I need to use this rules to translate a PSG tree into a CCG tree(or the reverse), but I found this may not be possible since for each POS tag, there are a lot of possible CCG tags generated from it. The number of possible CCG trees are huge. How can I limit the space of CCG trees to find a valid one?

Comment: What makes you think there is a) a not-inconsistent map>? b) a valid map?  b) a unique valid map?  What is taking the semantics of the sentences into account?  "Colorless green ideas slept furiously".

Comment: 1. Hockenmaier([2007](http://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/pdf/10.1162/coli.2007.33.3.355)) proposed an algorithm to convert a Penn Treebank into a CCG bank with high accuracy, this algorithm provides a set of rules which act as a unique valid map. 2. I'm sorry I don't quite understand the question, but the representation of semantics is a set of symbols, which can be seen as a abstraction of the set of words with the same fuction.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, CCGs have the same expressive power as the lambda calculus.  This means the CCG tree can be an arbitrarily complicated function of the original sentence.  And you're proposing to construct a mapping between PSG and a CCG by mere statistical counting or some such.  I don't see how this is possible in general, or why you should hope you can make it work for special cases [and you haven't identified any special cases here].  (For the CCG, the semantics of the words I guess are hiding in the grammar itself or at least in how it classifies its lexemes).

Comment: For example, the rules of transferring sentences(i) to (ii) can be simply concluded as: (a) If a root node's POS tag is S, then its corresponding CCG tag would be S. (b) If any node has a POS tag N(terminal) or NP(non-terminal), then its CCG tag is NP. (c) If a node has a parent POS tagged x with a brother POS tagged y, then its CCG tag is X/Y. These rules can also be learned from the mapping, since we have p(S|S) = 1, p(NP|n) = 1 and p()

Comment: EDIT for my comment: The symbols x, y and z are POS tags, while X, Y, Z are CCG tags. We want to learn the rule(c) through the mapping. If we estimate the rules p(X|x), p(Y|y) and p(X/Y|n,X,Y) by counting, we might get the rule p(X/Y|n,x,y) by induction since we have the CCG rule X/Y Y => X.

Comment: @GuyCoder Thanks! It seems more complicated than my problem. I'll take a close look.